# Online Backup for neo4j Community Edition

Tags: backup, neo4j

I'm looking for **Online backup** feature for **neo4j Community edition**. There is a component available for neo4j Enterprise, but couldn't find for Community edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The online backup is only available for the enterprise edition.

Answer (score 1):

You could always write your own ServerExtension or Plugin to export all or a sub-set of your data without shutting down the server or use something like the [Geoff-Plugin](https://github.com/neo4j/geoff-plugin) which exports data in a [human readable format](http://py2neo.org/geoff/) and can re-import it again.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I guess we can do the same thing using Gremlin export. Gremlin exports graph in GraphML.